# Flutter: using package under BSD License

Tags: package, licensing, bsd

Where do i have to link the copyright notice of a used package under BSD license in my App?

I am not publishing documentation or any source code of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps usually have a separate screen where they collect license and attribution notices. If your app has a settings screen, you could add an “about” section where you mention yourself and also link to the screen with open source libraries. Here's the Settings > About screen on the Todoist Android app, which is closed source:

> [image]
>
> Description: The “About” screen shows information about the app and about the company behind it. Under a headline “Legal”, there are entries for “Open source licenses”, “Privacy policy”, and “Terms of service”.

Most licenses (including most BSD license variants) require you to show the license even for binaries “in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution”. Whereas the manual was a reasonable place in the case of software distributed on physical installation media (e.g. floppy disks) or for software accompanied by electronic manuals (e.g. man-pages on Linux), there is no such accompanying material in the case of mobile apps. But this doesn't free you from having to show the license notices. Instead, these notices are typically shown *within* the app.